# Script error: " was not expected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch script which prompts for an input string, to be used as a filename prefix for fifteen files in my downloads directory. Then to remove the last seven characters of those filenames.

I get the error:

```
" was not expected at this time
```

I have tried running on an elevated and a regular Command Prompt and PowerShell, but I still get the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p prefix="Enter prefix for file names: "
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
set num=0
for /f "skip=%num%" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d') do (
   set "filename=%%~na"
   set "extension=%%~xa"
   set "newname=!prefix!%%filename:~0,-7!.!extension!"
   ren "%%a" "!newname!" >nul
   set /a num=num+1
   if !num! equ 15 goto done
)
:done
echo Done!
```

Comment: `skip=` does not allow `skip=0`. `!prefix! is not invalid, but implies that `prefix` is changing within the loop. I'd use `%prefix%` here. `%%filename:~0.-7!` should be  `!filename:~0.-7!` . The dot between `!filename...!` and `!extension!` would insert an extra `.` since `%%~xa` includes the dot. Try `echo ren ...` (and remove the `>nul`) to show a report of what the code intends to do without actually doing it.